# angular js module & architecture design: multiple index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngboilerplate, angular-seed

### Question:

I have a site where multiple ng-apps exists, each ng-app has a standalone folder of the architecture of  [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)(That means each folder has its own index.html). Now sharing modules between them is painful. Each app cannot use the same bower_components or any common services I wrote. How can I manage to do this?

### Uniqueness of my condition

Why do I separate them in different folders and use their own index.html? In my condition, different ng-app serves different types of user, whom would commonly login to one ng-app, one and only one. I don't want to load all the files for one specific ng-app.

### My trials:

I found that [this blog post](http://clintberry.com/2013/modular-angularjs-application-design/) has a usable architecture to use. It simply uses a MainApp module to include all the sub app modules. But wouldn't it be expensive for all the sub app files to load in one index.html on startup? For angular has its bad reputation of performance. or have I worried too much?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple index.html and in each one a different module? Did I understand correct? So you can use Dependency Injenction in a main module like in your link. Then you can share all the datas between them. For the routing you can user ngRoute like it is sais before, or even better the more advanced ui-router. According to your performance problem it depends on the size of the application, so you should tell more details. And you don't need to load all the files at the beginning, you can also load some files dynamicly when needed. You can user jQuery getScript like the following:

```
    if ($("css-selektor").length){
    $.getScript("file.js");
    }
```

Comment: what I prefer in this scenario is a round trip page between the index.html (modules) like in a normal webpage. And using the router inside each module.